# Mount unknown filesystem type - Debian

Tags: debian, filesystems, mount

Using *Debian 9.9* on a **live USB**, and try to mount a partition from de hdd

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

I get

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'
```

Well, the **ext4**, **ext3**, **ext2** type are not in `/proc/filesystem`

I have `e2fslibs` and `e2fsprogs` installed.

Comment: If you reboot do you still not have any ext file systems listed in `/proc/filesystem`?

Comment: This seems impossible unless maybe your live USB image is corrupt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Have a look at your kernel config. If `ext4` is built as module, then it should output `CONFIG_EXT4_FS=m` and a few more lines:

   ```
   $ grep 'CONFIG_EXT4_FS' /boot/config-$(uname -r)
   CONFIG_EXT4_FS=m
   CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
   CONFIG_EXT4_FS_SECURITY=y
   CONFIG_EXT4_FS_ENCRYPTION=y
   ```
2. Check that the module is present in your initrd image:

   ```
   $ zcat /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) | cpio -t | grep ext4
   lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/ext4
   lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/ext4/ext4.ko
   141243 blocks
   ```

   On my Debian Live 9.1 (bootet from USB with syslinux and persistence) the path of the loaded initrd is a bit different. The above file is the one present in the squashfs image. Just to make sure this is really the same file:

   ```
   $ dmesg | grep initrd
   [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/live/vmlinuz_4_9.0_4_amd64 initrd=/live/initrd_img_4_9.0_4_amd64 boot=live persistence components
   [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/live/vmlinuz_4_9.0_4_amd64 initrd=/live/initrd_img_4_9.0_4_amd64 boot=live persistence components
   [    0.870136] Freeing initrd memory: 22792K
   ```

   The path to initrd is `/live/initrd_img_4_9.0_4_amd64` and my boot files are mounted on `/lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1`. Your path is probably different.

   With both paths merged together:

   ```
   $ zcat /lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1/live/initrd_img_4_9.0_4_amd64 | cpio -t | grep ext4
   lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/ext4
   lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/kernel/fs/ext4/ext4.ko
   141243 blocks
   $ diff /lib/live/mount/persistence/sdb1/live/initrd_img_4_9.0_4_amd64 /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r)
   ```

   Confirmed, both files are the same.
3. Then the module should have been loaded:

   ```
   $ lsmod|grep ext4
   ext4                  585728  1
   crc16                  16384  1 ext4
   jbd2                  106496  1 ext4
   fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
   mbcache                16384  2 ext4
   $ cat /proc/filesystems | grep ext4
       ext4
   ```

Comment: What if the initial ram-disk does not have any `ext4.ko` and `insmod ext4` does not find it either? Also, `lsinitrd | grep` could be used instead of `zcat | cpio | grep`

Comment: @MartinZeitler If you don't have the module built-in with `CONFIG_EXT4_FS=y` then you need `ext4` to be present as module. Do you have a new question?